# PHP ODBC: How to avoid "No tuples ..." error

Tags: php, odbc, tuples, resultset

I use procedures that return various count of result sets. There is no problem if there is one or more result sets. I can switch from one to other using odbc_next_result(). It detects "no more results" by returning false. The problem occurs if the procedure returns no result. The first fetch (using various function) returns error "No tuples available at this result index". How to avoid this error?

```
$result=odbc_exec($dbconnection,$sql);
```

The $sql variable can contain any sql batch with many commands that can produce result sets or none. How can I detect the $result does not contain any result set?

Comment: Avoid? Or just avoid displaying?

Comment: Avoid. I know the @ character, but I dont like to supress any warnings in my software.